# Symfony - default (empty) entries in form being rendered?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have 2 simple Symfony questions

**Question 1:** Using FormBuilderInterface in Symfony 4, I have this segment of code:

```
->add('actions', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => ActionType::class,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'collection_item_class' => '',
            'prototype_name' => 'action',
            'prototype_data' => new Action(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'error_bubbling' => false,
            'delete_empty' => true,
        ])
```

This is rendering an empty row in the form, see below:
[empty row being rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi21L.png)

I can't find anywhere to stop rendering a blank row.

**Question 2**: When using FormBuilderInterface, how do I introduce simple conditional logic to the below segment:

```
->add('statusChoice', ChoiceType::class, [
            'expanded' => true,
            'choices' => [
                'Approve' => 'approved',
                'Decline' => 'declined',
            ]
        ])
        ->add('declinedReason', TextareaType::class)
```

'declinedReason' would be required if the person has chosen 'Decline'/'decline' in the above radio button. I'm aware how to do this with something like jQuery, but not sure with Symfony.

Thank you :)

Comment: I don't understand question 1. As for question 2, I would do what you suggested with jQuery. Hide the field with JS unless/until you need it.

Comment: 'Base' symfony does not render any initial entry or provide any js, so that depends on your theme or what additional packages you are using. As for the second, you can create a custom constraint or use [`Callback`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) or [`Expression`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html).

Comment: I answered a quite similar question regarding your second point [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64346340#64381651).