# How to set required depends on choice type in symfony?

Tags: symfony

In have the form builder :

```
 $formBuilder->add('customDuplicatedId', TextType::class,
            [
                'required' => false,
                'data' => implode(",", $duplicatedIds),
                'mapped' => false,
                'help' => "Enter singleCheck Id separate by ',' "
            ]
        )
        ->add('isDuplicated', ChoiceType::class,
            [
                'required' => true,
                'data' => $entity->getSingleCheck()->isDuplicated(),
                'mapped' => false,
                'label' => 'Hidden (duplicated)',
                'expanded' => true,
                'choices'  => [
                    'Yes' => true,
                    'No' => false,
                ],
                'placeholder' => false
            ]);
```

I would like when user choose `Yes`, the text input will required. When user choose `No` , the text input will not required. How can I do that?

Comment: You cannot achieve that kind of logic directly from the form builder. You'll need to implement a custom class level validator for validating this rule on backend  - and a javascript part that will update the second input field to be required/optional based on the first selection (well, the javascript part is optional but it will result in more intuitive form for the end users)..

Comment: You can use following approach: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html to add required field or a constraint to it basing on posted value from another field.
You can also create a special group only with validation for your text field: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_based_validation.html

Or use `PRE_SUBMIT` form event to check value of posted field and replace existing field with NotBlank constraint for text field.

Comment: @ejuhjav Definitely the way to go if you want reusability, but not _completely_ accurate. Check my answer.

Comment: @msg nice - didn't know that was possible. I'm not sure if I would opt to use that approach in any scenario but it's always good to learn new things :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using a [`Callback`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) constraint. It is almost like defining a [custom constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html) (and definitely the way to go if you plan on reusing the logic) but you can use a closure or other callable directly in the form type (check the reference).

```
->add('customDuplicatedId', TextType::class,
    [
        // Other options omitted
        'constraints' => new Callback(
            function($duplicateId, ExecutionContextInterface $context) {
                // Get the field we depend on by traversing the form
                // Current field: customDuplicateId
                $duplicated = $context->getObject()
                      // Parent: Form
                      ->getParent()
                      // Field isDuplicated -> value
                      ->get('isDuplicated')->getData();
                // 'choices' returns a bool in this case, so just apply logic
                if ($duplicated && empty($duplicateId)) {
                    $context->buildViolation('This value is required')
                        ->atPath('customDuplicatedId')
                        ->addViolation();
                }
            }
        ),
    ]
)
```

It is also possible to set the constraint globally in the form `defaults` without binding it to an specific field and use the `context` to access the targets. In a case like this where you need access to multiple fields it might be clearer. In that situation the first argument will be empty and `getObject` will return the form itself (so there's no need to call `getParent`).

In a custom form type class:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'constraints' => // ...
    ]);
}
```

Creating a builder in a controller (extending `AbstractController`):

```
$builder = $this->createFormBuilder($data, [ 'constraints' => /* ... */ ]);
$builder->add(/* ... */);
```